# get feature names from Sklearn LabelBinarizer

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

The documentation and a few related post lead me to believe I should be able to get the feature names from the labels scikit-learn's LabelBinarizer is one-hot encoding.

I have a pipeline defined as following:

```
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('selector', DataFrameSelector(cat_attribs)),
        ('label_binarizer', LabelBinarizer()),
    ])
```

This works just fine, (note that DataFrameSelector is a custom class), however, it seems like I could extract the feature names like this:

```
feature_names = cat_pipeline.named_steps['label_binarizer'].get_feature_names()
```

I also tried substituting `get_feature_names()` with `get_support()` to not avail.

This is possible when using LabelEncoder on its own outside of a pipeline before one hot encoding as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
housing_cat = housing["ocean_proximity"]
housing_cat_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(housing_cat)
housing_cat_encoded
print(encoder.classes_)
```

For further context please see the notebook I am working through:

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb

Comment: I think the jupyter notebook is too long, so that's why I didn't go through it and try to answer your question. It's not clear to me exactly what is and is not working for you in the code you've posted above. Also, it's hard to get started trying to help because there's no small amount of code I can copy and play with (again the notebook is too long and what you have above doesn't work on its own without any data). I figured I'd mention all this so you could change the question some and hopefully get some help

Comment: @Ryan Stout I gave the jupyter notebook as context, but I think a person who is able to answer this question will have done exactly what I am attempting to do before, has a strong understanding of the sklearn class, or someone who has gone through the notebook themselves as the publication is relatively prominent. What I want to accomplish might not even be supported in a straightforward way for all I know.